# iOS: App Home Button Shortcut

Tags: ios

Having trouble finding the API for the home screen shortcuts when the home button is clicked. My app plays audio and I want those similar shortcuts to pop up like the do for the iPod to give me the option to stop playback.

Can someone just point me to the reference?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by home screen shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good place to start:

[Remote Control Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW3)

From the Apple documentation:

> Test that your app is properly receiving and handling remote control
>   events with the Now Playing Controls. These controls are available on
>   recent iOS devices that are running iOS 4.0 or later. To access these
>   controls, press the Home button twice, then flick right along the
>   bottom of the screen until you find the audio playback controls. These
>   controls send remote control events to the app that is currently or
>   was most recently playing audio. The icon to the right of the playback
>   controls represents the app that is currently receiving the remote
>   control events.

Comment: I couldn't quite find it in there. I figured out how do use the headphone remote, but can't find anywhere to make a shortcut view. Little help plz? I don't mean to make you do my work for me I just really couldn't find it and don't quite have the knowledge to find the right place to look.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "shortcut view". If you mean the playback control buttons on the left most part of multitasking bar or on the lock screen when you press home button twice this is it. There is the same API to get control events from buttons mentioned above and remote on your headphones.

Comment: Ah OK Amazing thanks I must just not be receiving the events properly but ya thats the exact snippet I was looking for.